# Maximising a partly concave and partly convex function

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable and strictly increasing function. Suppose that we are searching for the numbers $x_1$, ..., $x_n$ that maximise

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{f(x_i)}$$

subject to the constraints that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{x_i}=\bar{x}$ and $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$.

If $f$ is strictly concave everywhere, it is optimal to set $x_i = x_j$ for every $i$ and $j$ (so that $x_i^* = \bar{x}/n$ for all $i$). If $f$ is strictly convex everwhere, it is optimal to set $x_i=\bar{x}$ and $x_j=0$ for some arbitrary $i$ and all $j\neq i$. However, I am interested in the 'mixed' case where $f$ has at least one convex portion but is ultimately concave.

Specifically, suppose that $f$ is strictly concave for all $x \geq \hat{x}$. Does this imply that $x_i^* = x_j^*$ provided that $\bar{x}$ is 'large enough'? If so, what precisely is the assumption that we need to make about $\bar{x}$? If not, are there some additional assumptions we can make to ensure that $x_i^* = x_j^*$?

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:** It has been pointed out that $f′(x_i^*)=f′(x_j^*)$ whenever $x_i^*>0$ and $x_j^*>0$. This might be a useful step towards an answer.

**Edit 2:** It has occurred to me that we will probably need to assume something like $f'(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ in order to ensure that $x_i^* = x_j^*$.

Comment: Can you assume that $f$ is *quasiconcave*?

Comment: I think so. My understanding is that any monotone function is quasi-concave. Since $f$ is monotonically increasing, this would imply that it is quasi-concave.

Comment: I guess a sufficient condition would be $f''(\bar x/n)<0$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - but why would this be sufficient?

Comment: $f''(\bar x/n)<0$ ensures that the FOCs $f'(x_i^*)=0$ ($i=1,\dots,n$) have a solution $x_i^*=\bar x/n$ that is a maximizer, not a minimizer.

Comment: Right but surely there are many solutions to that first-order condition? e.g. If the function is convex then concave, then the derivative will first increase and then decrease. So there could be many pairs of points where the derivatives are equal. e.g. take $f'(x)=x$ for $x \leq 1$ and $f'(x)=1-x$ for $x > 1$ (admittedly the function won't be twice differentiable but this probably still illustrates the point). Many of these pairs will involve $x_i \neq x_j$.

Comment: Sure, there could be many solutions to the FOCs. That's why you need the condition on the second derivative to ensure that the solution indeed maximizes the objective function. Since the object function is quasiconcave, there is a unique maximum.

Comment: So to clarify: while $f$ is quasi-concave, the objective function $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{f(x_i)}$ need not be quasi-concave -- at least, unless we place some restriction on $\bar{x}$ (and perhaps make additional assumptions).

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

*If $f$ is strictly convex everywhere, it is optimal to set $x_i
=\overline x$ and $x_j =0$ for some arbitrary $i$ and all $j\ne i$.*

I assume from this that the $x_i$ are constrained to be non-negative?

---

Using the Lagrange multiplier technique with Lagrangian $L=\sum_i f(x_i)-\lambda (\sum_i x_i-\overline x)$, we can conclude that the stationary points occur when $\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}x}\big{|}_{x_i}=\lambda$. Furthermore, if some of the $x_i$ are assigned to be zero then we can use the same Lagrange multiplier technique on all of the remaining unassigned $x_i$.

Hence we can deduce that $\sum f(x_i)$ is maximised when, at all of the $x_i$ which do not satisfy $x_i=0$, $f(x)$ has the same derivative.

---

As an example, consider the case when $f(x)=(x-1)^3$ and $n=2$. If there is a maximum with $x_1$ and $x_2$ both non-zero, then it must be the case that $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}=3(x-1)^2$ is the same at $x_1$ and $x_2$.

For $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be distinct we would have to have $x_1=1+\sqrt a, \ x_2=1-\sqrt a$ for some constant $a$. Therefore, it $\overline x \ne 2$, then at the maximum either $x_1=x_2$ or $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\overline x$. On the other hand, if $\overline x=2$ then, for any $0\le a \le 1$, there is a maximum with $x_1=1+\sqrt a, \ x_2=1-\sqrt a$ and $\sum_i f(x_i)=0$.

---

Finally, there is one point that I would like to make about eventually concave functions. The function graphed below contains a section which is strictly convex but very close to being a horizontal line followed by a section which is strictly concave but is very close to being a straight line. Even for rather large $\overline x$, the maxima will satisfy $x_i=\overline x$ and $x_j=0$ for $j \ne i$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) Yes, I did want to constrain the $x_i$ to be non-negative - apologies for forgetting to state this! 2) I completely agree that the derivatives must be the same in the interior, i.e. $f'(x_i)=f'(x_j)$ whenever it is optimal to set $x_i>0$ and $x_j>0$. 3) I am a bit confused about your example $f(x)=(x−1)^3$ -- this function is first concave then convex, whereas I am looking at the reverse case! 4) More generally, can you think of a sufficient condition to ensure that $x_i=x_j$ at the optimum?